# RabbitMQ not starting on Win10 - init terminating in do_boot

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, message-queue

Trying to sort out why my local RabbitMQ is not starting.
I had an issue with a previous version of RabbitMQ on the system not starting, so I decided to uninstall it and reinstall using chocolaty. The service wasn't starting after having quite a few messages in the queue, system going to sleep and restarting multiple times... The uninstall did remove all the files from the AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ directory, the service wasn't running, and the system was rebooted.

Currently have RabbitMQ 3.8.2, which installed with Erlang20.0

Here's the snipped from the rabbit log file:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:24 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.6.11 on Erlang 20.0
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:24 ===
node           : rabbit@myhostname
home dir       : C:\WINDOWS
config file(s) : c:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : a hash goes here
log            : C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/RABBIT~1.LOG
sasl log       : C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/RABBIT~2.LOG
database dir   : c:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:25 ===
RabbitMQ hasn't finished starting yet. Waiting for startup to finish before stopping...
=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:31 ===
Memory high watermark set to 6505 MiB (6821275238 bytes) of 16263 MiB (17053188096 bytes) total

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:31 ===
Enabling free disk space monitoring

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:31 ===
Disk free limit set to 50MB

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:31 ===
Limiting to approx 8092 file handles (7280 sockets)

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:31 ===
FHC read buffering:  OFF
FHC write buffering: ON

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:31 ===
Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:31 ===
Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:31 ===
Priority queues enabled, real BQ is rabbit_variable_queue

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:52 ===
Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,
       {error,
           {{shutdown,
                {failed_to_start_child,rabbit_epmd_monitor,
                    {{badmatch,noport},
                     [{rabbit_epmd_monitor,init,1,
                          [{file,"src/rabbit_epmd_monitor.erl"},{line,56}]},
                      {gen_server,init_it,2,
                          [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,365}]},
                      {gen_server,init_it,6,
                          [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,333}]},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                          [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}}},
            {child,undefined,rabbit_epmd_monitor_sup,
                {rabbit_restartable_sup,start_link,
                    [rabbit_epmd_monitor_sup,
                     {rabbit_epmd_monitor,start_link,[]},
                     false]},
                transient,infinity,supervisor,
                [rabbit_restartable_sup]}}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/RABBIT~1.LOG
   C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/RABBIT~2.LOG


=ERROR REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:53 ===
Error trying to stop RabbitMQ: error:{badmatch,false}
=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jan-2020::19:39:53 ===
Halting Erlang VM with the following applications:
    sasl
    stdlib
    kernel
```

Not a lot of help to a new RabbitMQ user trying to get an install working.
This is the first few lines from the erl_crash.dump file in the same dir as the logs:

```
=erl_crash_dump:0.3
Wed Jan 22 20:38:13 2020
Slogan: init terminating in do_boot ({undef,[{rabbit_nodes_common,make,rabbit@myhostname,[]},{rabbit_prelaunch,start,0,[{_},{_}]},{init,start_em,1,[{_},{_}]},{init,do_boot,3,[{_},{_}]}]})
System version: Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10]
Compiled: Tue Jun 20 19:49:32 2017
```

I've been going through the the docs [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting.html), but haven't found much of a solution to this.

Comment: Your log shows RabbitMQ 3.6.11, yet you say you're using 3.8.2 with Erlang 20. 3.8.2 won't work with Erlang 20. There are too many inconsistencies with your environment to continue assisting. I suggest removing all traces of RabbitMQ and Erlang, and starting over with RabbitMQ 3.8.2 and Erlang 22.2